# Thumb moved on it's own when I didn't animate it

Tags: animation, rigify

I don't know what is happening to my rig, because for some reason, the right thumb moved on it's own only on the last (for now) animation I was working on. I already finished a couple of animations and this is the only time I got this weird issue. Here's what the thumb looks like on the current animation I'm working on:

[image]

It seems to be just going down. I don't think it's following the right foot because on the animation I was doing some sort of stomping motion on the right foot, and when the right foot was raised, the right thumb was already almost at the bottom of right hand. It looks like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove the thumb from all vertex groups and reassign to the correct vertex group?

Comment: From the screenshots, it is unclear whether this is a rig issue or a skinning issue. Can you verify that the bones are behaving as expected, and that it is just the skinned mesh that's deforming unexpectedly? It will speed things up if you can share the file.

Comment: It seems like the thumb bones on the animation is moving on it's own. I added the file so you can check it. The specific animation that is having the issue is called "rig_ox_summon_wall"

Comment: You've keyframed location onto thumb.01_master.R .  So, your thumb moves.  To fix, delete the keyframes on this bone (they don't do anything else.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that thing moved. Thanks a lot, man.

Answer (score 2):

The bone "thumb.01_master.R" has wrong key-frames.

Look at the picture below :
[image: wrong key-frames]

Comment: Yeah, a guy commented about that above. Thanks anyway